# Flaskrestx swagger page empty w apache proxy

Tags: python, apache, flask, swagger, flask-restx

I'm using Flaskrestx and Apache to try and display a swagger page. On my local machine, it comes up just fine at http://localhost:5000/. But on my server, I just get an empty page.

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myserver.com

  ## docroot
  DocumentRoot "/etc/httpd/htdocs"
  ## Logging
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_error_log"
  CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/httpd_access_log"
  ServerSignature Off

  SetEnv HTTPS On
  <Location "/my_api">

    ProxyPass http://0.0.0.0:5000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://0.0.0.0:5000/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The message I'm seeing my my apache error logs is:

```
<my_laptop_ip> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "(GET /my_api/ HTTP/1.1)" 200 1397 "(ref -)" "(client Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36)"
<router_ip_a> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "GET /my_api/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1397 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
<my_laptop_ip> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "(GET /swaggerui/droid-sans.css HTTP/1.1)" 404 196 "(ref https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/)" "(client Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36)"
<router_ip_a> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "GET /swaggerui/droid-sans.css HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
<my_laptop_ip> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "(GET /swaggerui/swagger-ui.css HTTP/1.1)" 404 196 "(ref https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/)" "(client Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36)"
<router_ip_a> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "GET /swaggerui/swagger-ui.css HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
<my_laptop_ip> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "(GET /swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js HTTP/1.1)" 404 196 "(ref https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/)" "(client Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36)"
<router_ip_a> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "GET /swaggerui/swagger-ui-bundle.js HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
<my_laptop_ip> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "(GET /swaggerui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/1.1)" 404 196 "(ref https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/)" "(client Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36)"
<router_ip_a> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "GET /swaggerui/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "https://devbox.aws_url.com/my_api/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
<router_ip_b> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "(GET / HTTP/1.0)" 200 114 "(ref -)" "(client -)"
<router_ip_b> - - [23/May/2023:16:43:43 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 114 "-" "-"
```

I don't understand what's happening here. apidoc.py for Flask-restx does define the static_url_path for swagger as /swaggerui but what do I need to do to let apache display my swagger page?